# multi character separated sort

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

How can I sort `!!` delimited records using `sort` command?

for File1

```
1!!2!!3
2!3!!3!!1
3!!2!!2
```

expected output

```
2!3!!3!!1
3!!2!!2   
1!!2!!3
```

then

```
sort -t \!\! -k 3 file1
```

RESULT:

```
sort: multi-character tab ‘!!’
```

why isn't it working?

Comment: What is it doing?  Giving an error?  Post the actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-character delimiters are not allowed in `sort -t` but you can just use:

```
sort -t '!' -k1 file
1!!b!!c
2!!f!!w
4!!e!!e
```

---

**EDIT:** If `!` can be there in data itself you can use this trick:

```
sed 's/!!/\x06/g' file | sort -t $'\x06' -k1 | sed 's/\x06/!!/g'
1!!b!!c
2!!f!!w
4!!e!!e
```

---

**EDIT2:** For doing this in single command use `awk`:

```
awk -F '!!' -v k=1 '{a[$k,$0]=$0} 
   END{asort(a, b, "@ind_num_asc"); for (i in b) print b[i]}' file
```

Comment: but what if the data have '!' within it?

Comment: is it possible to use special unicode charecter say ‘৯’

Comment: If that Unicode character is supported in your Unix terminal locale then sure you can.